# OleDbAdapters doesn't read dates in different formats from single excel column

Tags: c#, excel, date-formatting, oledbdataadapter

I am reading an excel file in my application. I use an OleDbDataAdapter to read and DataTable to store records from .xlsx file. I have problem reading different date formats from single column. My column looks like that:

```
 2014-02-07 
 2014-02-05 
 27.01.2014 
 19.11.2013
 2014-02-07
 2014-02-07
```

My program loads only dates in "yyyy-MM-dd" format and rest of them are DBNull.Value. Is there any way to read whole column as strings (so i can manipulate them manualy) or to force OleDbDataAdapter to read all dates?

Thats my code:

```
        var fileName = string.Format(@"C:\28.xlsx");
        var connectionstring = string.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 xml;HDR=NO;IMEX=1'");

        var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$B12:L]", connectionstring);
        var ds = new DataSet();

        adapter.Fill(ds, "anyNameHere");
        System.Data.DataTable data = ds.Tables["anyNameHere"];

        foreach (DataRow row in data.Rows)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine(row.Field<DateTime>(3).ToShortDateString());
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine(row.Field<string>(3));
            }
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

OleDb figures out the column data type based on the first row's content (if headers available, the one after the header) and applies it to the rest of the rows.

So I would suggest to change the column's data format to text rather than Date/time and then deal with them on C# side.